# PLSQL: ORA-14552 Cannot perform DDL, Commit

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, procedure

In my PLSQL function, for writing loggers to log table i am calling a procedure (which contains commit statement). So i declared it as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PR_LOGGER
( IN PARAMETERS-----)
IS Pragma Autonomous_transaction
BEGIN

--Insert statements

Commit;
END;
```

CALLING FUNCTION:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MYFUNCTION
( --IN PARAMETERS )
BEGIN

---Some select statements
PR_LOGGER(logmessage);
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE tablename';
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS
   IF (SQLCODE !=942 ) THEN
   PR_LOGGER(SQLERRM);
   END IF;
END;
return NULL;
END;
```

So i understand if calling procedure or function contains commit, i will get ORA-14552  but even though i am handing it as Pragma Autonomous_transaction to avoid that error , i am still getting the same error. Any idea what i am doing wrong? Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DROP TABLE` statement causes an implicit commit.

The `PRAGMA` only applies to the execution of the `PROCEDURE`.

The `DROP TABLE` isn't executed in the context of the procedure. That's in the body, executed in the context, of the `FUNCTION`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Should i not use drop table inside my function at all? can you advise the best way to do it

Comment: Right. Don't perform DDL operations in the context of a FUNCTION.  You already figured out how you can do a commit, using an autonomous transaction. You can do the same thing with the DROP TABLE. Put that into a PROCEDURE, and call the procedure from the FUNCTION.

Comment: Thanks so much :) Will try that